# Why Windows mouse hook in Excel-VBA slows down Excel if there isn't userform?

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, hook

I'm setting simple mouse hook like that:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As LongPtr, ByVal lpFn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As LongPtr, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As LongPtr

Private HookHandle As LongPtr

Private Const WH_MOUSE = 7

Public Sub RemoveHook()
    On Error Resume Next
    UnhookWindowsHookEx HookHandle
End Sub

Public Sub SetHook()
    HookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, AddressOf NewProc, 0, GetCurrentThreadId)
End Sub

Public Function NewProc(ByVal lngCode As LongPtr, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    NewProc = CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, lngCode, wParam, lParam)
    Exit Function
End Function
```

and Excel slows down so much, that I can barely kill it.
But when I do that in userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    SetHook
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    RemoveHook
End Sub
```

It works normal. My question is WHY?

Comment: Probably related to the message processing of Excel. Excel is the wrong place to be writing such code.

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem. What do you need a mouse hook for?

Comment: David: so I can't make hook to any process?
Mathieu: I just want to undestand it better.